# Python script output as Ansible inventory file

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

Hi I have a Python script `apihosts.py` which pulls list of server names from API url.

```bash
# python apihosts.py

server1
server2
server3
server4
```

How can I input them as inventory file to my Ansible playbook?

Tried the below

```bash
# ansible-playbook temp.yml -i apihosts.py
```

and got an error

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/apihosts.py with ini plugin: /home/apihosts.py:1: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: requests
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Comment: Why not write the output of the API call into an INI file like Ansible is expecting?

Comment: You may have a look into [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) first.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#inventory-plugins